# Minimum example for replying to a message via BotFramework's REST API?

Tags: python, botframework

Within my Python webapp for the [Microsoft Botframework](http://docs.botframework.com), I want to [reply to a message](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/replying/#replying-to-the-message-later) with a [REST API call](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi/#!/Messages/Messages_SendMessage) to `/bot/v1.0/messages`.

When experimenting with the emulator on my local machine, I realized that the minimum payload for the REST call is something like:

```json
{
  "text": "Hello, Hello!",
  "from": {
    "address": "MyBot"
  },
  "channelConversationId": "ConvId"
}
```

where `"ConvId"` is the id given by my local emulator in the original message (Note, that I have to send `channelConversationId` not `conversationId`).

Obviously, this is not enough for the live bot connector site. But what is a (minimum) example for replying to a message with the REST API call `/bot/v1.0/messages`?

I've tested different payload data, for example with attributes `from`, `to`, `channelConversationId`, `text`and `language` as indicated in the docs. But usually I get a `500` error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}
```

When I tried to send back the original message, just with `to` and `from` swapped, I got a different `500` error:

```json
{
  "error": {
     "code": "ServiceError",
     "message": "*Sorry, Web Chat is having a problem responding right now.*",
     "statusCode": 500
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum payload for an inline reply (returned as the response) is:

```
{ "text": "Hello, Hello!" }
```

If you're posting a reply to  out of band using a POST to `/bot/v1.0/messages` then you're correct you need a little more. Here's what I do in the Node version of the Bot Builder SDK:

```
// Post an additional reply
reply.from = ses.message.to;
reply.to = ses.message.replyTo ? ses.message.replyTo : ses.message.from;
reply.replyToMessageId = ses.message.id;
reply.conversationId = ses.message.conversationId;
reply.channelConversationId = ses.message.channelConversationId;
reply.channelMessageId = ses.message.channelMessageId;
reply.participants = ses.message.participants;
reply.totalParticipants = ses.message.totalParticipants;
this.emit('reply', reply);
post(this.options, '/bot/v1.0/messages', reply, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        this.emit('error', err);
    }
});
```

Sending a reply to an existing conversation is a little complicated because you have to include all of the routing bits needed to get it back to the source conversation. Starting a new conversation is significantly easier:

```
// Start a new conversation
reply.from = ses.message.from;
reply.to = ses.message.to;
this.emit('send', reply);
post(this.options, '/bot/v1.0/messages', reply, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        this.emit('error', err);
    }
});
```

Both examples assume that `reply.text` & `reply.language` has already been set.

Comment: Thank you Steven! What's inside the properties `reply.to` and `reply.from`? Are all 4 sub-properties required (`channelId`, `address`, `name` and `id`)? Maybe you could add a JSON representation of `reply`. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again Steven, meanwhile, the answer was posted on GitHub with additional info. Thus I wrote a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, the answer has been posted to [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/141), quoting [wiltodelta](https://github.com/wiltodelta)

> Experimentally found necessary parameters for Slack, Skype, Telegram: ... ChannelConversationId only necessary Slack, otherwise the message will be added @userAddress.

```js
Message message = new Message
{
  ChannelConversationId = channelConversationId,
  From = new ChannelAccount
  {
    ChannelId = channelId,
    Address = botAddress,
    IsBot = true
  },
  To = new ChannelAccount
  {
    ChannelId = channelId,
    Address = userAddress
  },
  Text = text
};
```

Especially, the attributes `replyToMessageId` and `channelConversationId` (earlier mentioned) are not necessary: They refer to the last seen message in the conversation and thus will change during a conversation.